# MethodIntercept with groovy

Tags: groovy

I have written a small piece of code in groovy. I have 2 methods 1) `generateAll` and other 2) `validate`. The idea was to intercept the call to `generateAll`. Validate the input first and then proceed for `generateAll`. I don't know why but 
`this.metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args)` always gives me null for `validate` method. However if I don't pass the arguments it finds the method but later breaks because of wrong number of arguments passed.

```
class CreateAllScripts implements GroovyInterceptable {
   void generateAll(String configName) {
   //DO some stuff
   }

   def invokeMethod(String name, args) {
      if (name == 'generateAll') {
         //First validate the config
         validate(args);
      }
      def method = this.metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args)
      method.invoke(this, args)
   }

   private void validate(String configName) {
      println("Validating")
      //perform some validation.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in how you pass arguments to `validate`. `*` operator should be used:

```
class CreateAllScripts implements GroovyInterceptable {
    void generateAll(String configName) {
        System.out.println("generating: $configName")
    }

    def invokeMethod(String name, args) {
        System.out.println("$name $args")
        if (name == 'generateAll') {
            validate(*args)
        }
        def method = this.metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args)
        method.invoke(this, args)    
    }

    private void validate(String configName) {
        System.out.println("validating: $configName")
    }
}
new CreateAllScripts().generateAll('aaa')
```

If simply `validate(args)` is called the output will be:

```
generateAll [aaa]
validate [[aaa]]
Exception thrown
```

Do you see that `aaa` was wrapped into a second list? That causes the problem. There's no method with name *validate* that accepts a **collection**.

Now, `validate(*args)` gives the following output:

```
generateAll [aaa]
validate [aaa]
validating: aaa
generating: aaa
```

Which is correct. On *dynamic* method invocation args should be generally passed with `*`.